# Unicode border drawing characters (NOT box drawing characters)

Tags: unicode

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing, I couldn't really find any other way to describe it.

The standard unicode box-drawing characters are positioned in the center of a character cell. This can cause visual discontinuity when these characters are used to draw borders for windows; because they are positioned in the center, there is empty space between the the bordering cells and the actual border. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

Is there an equivalent for unicode box drawing characters that are aligned to the right/left/top/bottom edges of a character box, so that there is no empty space between the character and bordering cell?

There are left and right aligned bar characters, such as `⎸`, but they don't compose into a nice continuous line like the box drawing chars do.

Comment: if there's no empty space between the border and the content inside then the whole thing is just an orange rectangle, what's the point of the border character?

Comment: I also see this. I am using unicode block characters and ANSI colours to display enlarged image data. It is much as drawn in the image: you can get a thin line of the background colour around the foreground block. I see this on the lower border, and on the right too for some font sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I could find:

```
▁ U+2581 LOWER ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
▏ U+258F LEFT ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
▔ U+2594 UPPER ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
▕ U+2595 RIGHT ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
```

Left/right tuck right up to the FULL BLOCK on my display, but upper/lower don't.  The font in my browser has the lower one narrower than the upper one as well.

```
  ▁▁▁
▕████▏
  ▔▔
```

Full list of `BLOCK` characters (display depends on the font):

```
␗ U+2417 SYMBOL FOR END OF TRANSMISSION BLOCK
▀ U+2580 UPPER HALF BLOCK
▁ U+2581 LOWER ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
▂ U+2582 LOWER ONE QUARTER BLOCK
▃ U+2583 LOWER THREE EIGHTHS BLOCK
▄ U+2584 LOWER HALF BLOCK
▅ U+2585 LOWER FIVE EIGHTHS BLOCK
▆ U+2586 LOWER THREE QUARTERS BLOCK
▇ U+2587 LOWER SEVEN EIGHTHS BLOCK
█ U+2588 FULL BLOCK
▉ U+2589 LEFT SEVEN EIGHTHS BLOCK
▊ U+258A LEFT THREE QUARTERS BLOCK
▋ U+258B LEFT FIVE EIGHTHS BLOCK
▌ U+258C LEFT HALF BLOCK
▍ U+258D LEFT THREE EIGHTHS BLOCK
▎ U+258E LEFT ONE QUARTER BLOCK
▏ U+258F LEFT ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
▐ U+2590 RIGHT HALF BLOCK
▔ U+2594 UPPER ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
▕ U+2595 RIGHT ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
```